# gtk# ScrolledWindow - scroll to top

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I have ScrolledWindow (inside is a TreeView) and I need to scroll to top. Do you have some idea? 
Every answer would be very appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GTk+ you basically get the vertical adjustment for the scrolled window and use it to set the scroll position.  I don't know gtk# details, but here's how in c++ (gtkmm):

```
 scrollWin.get_vadjustment()->set_value(0);
```

Gtk# should be similar.

Answer (score 1):

In GTK# for a variable named `scrollWin` of type `GtkScrolledWindow`

```
scrollWin.Vadjustment.Value = 0;
```